# ERROR: repository hyperledger/fabric-tools not found: does not exist or no pull access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to start up network using following command

> ./network_setup.sh up

After running this command I am receiving this errro

> #
>   
>   #    Generating anchor peer update for Org2MSP
>   
>   ########################################################### 2017-06-05 18:16:35.716 CST [common/configtx/tool] main -> INFO 001
>
> Loading configuration 2017-06-05 18:16:35.719 CST
>   [common/configtx/tool] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 002
>   Generating anchor peer update 2017-06-05 18:16:35.719 CST
>   [common/configtx/tool] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 003 Writing
>   anchor peer update
>
> Pulling cli (hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest)... 
>   ERROR: repository hyperledger/fabric-tools not found: does not exist or no pull access
>   ERROR !!!! Unable to pull the images

How I can remove this error?please help me

Comment: Post the content of your `network_setup.sh` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually pull this (and any other Hyperledger Fabric image) image from DockerHub. There was a period when the fabric-tools image was not included in the helper script `download-dockerimages.sh`.

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0-beta 
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0-beta hyperledger/fabric-tools
```

Note that it might be worth reviewing the set of published tags on DockerHub to be sure you are getting the latest.

https://hub.docker.com/u/hyperledger/

Answer (score 0):

you write the command line : this :

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.1.0-rc1
```

after that

```
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.1.0-rc1 hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
```